# get the last token of a string in C

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok

what I want to do is given an input string, which I will **not** know it's size or the number of tokens, be able to print it's last token.

e.x.:

```
char* s = "some/very/big/string";
char* token;

const char delimiter[2] = "/";

token = strtok(s, delimiter);

while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}

return token;
```

and i want my return to be

> string

but I what I get is (null). Any workarounds? I've searched  the web and can't seem to find an answer to this. At least for C programming language.

Comment: You can use basename API in C.                                                         char *basename(char *path);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you tokenize on a specific character, i.e. `'/'` in your example, you do not need to tokenize the string at all: call [`strrchr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strrchr.html) to find the position of the last `'/'`, and add `1` to the resultant pointer to skip the delimiter, like this:

```
char *s = "some/very/big/string";
char *last = strrchr(s, '/');
if (last != NULL) {
    printf("Last token: '%s'\n", last+1);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Rh48DL)

Comment: @Sanaf `last++` isn't the same; you need `++last` t if you want it to point at the final token.

Answer (score 4):

Just use another variable to store last token before it gets null

```
char s[] = "some/very/big/string";
char * token, * last;
last = token = strtok(s, "/");
for (;(token = strtok(NULL, "/")) != NULL; last = token);
printf("%s\n", last);
```

Comment: @bisuke It's a simplification. You could rewrite it to something like: 
`while(token != NULL)
    {
        last = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
`